How to use this resource correctly iosxe_restconf from terraform-provider-iosxe?
I have this result (AAA configuration) generated from restconf API using postman.
https://{{host}}:{{port}}/restconf/data/Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native/aaa/authentication.
{
    "Cisco-IOS-XE-aaa:authentication": {
        "attempts": {
            "login": 4
        },
        "enable": {
            "default": {
                "group": "tacacs+",
                "enable": [
                    null
                ]
            }
        },
        "login": [
            {
                "name": "default",
                "a1": {
                    "local": [
                        null
                    ]
                },
                "a2": {
                    "group": "tacacs+"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

How i can translate this code into correct terraform code using provider terraform-provider-iosxe.
I tried this 2 code below, and having an error after applying the code.
1st code - Result is Error
resource "iosxe_restconf" "aaa_authentication" {
  path = "Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native/aaa/authentication"
  attributes = {
    "attempts/login" = 4
    "enable/default/group"  = "tacacs+"
    "enable/default/enable" = null
    "login/name"            = "default"
    "login/a1/local"        = null
    "login/a2/group"        = "tacacs+"
  }
}

Output :
Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
iosxe_restconf.aaa_authentication: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Client Error
│ 
│   with iosxe_restconf.aaa_authentication,
│   on main.tf line 175, in resource "iosxe_restconf" "aaa_authentication":
│  175: resource "iosxe_restconf" "aaa_authentication" {
│ 
│ Failed to configure object (PATCH), got error: HTTP Request failed: StatusCode 400, RESTCONF errors {Error:[{ErrorType:application ErrorTag:malformed-message ErrorAppTag: ErrorPath:/Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native/aaa/Cisco-IOS-XE-aaa:authentication ErrorMessage:0: Internal error ErrorInfo:}]} {PatchId: GlobalStatus:{Ok:false Errors:{Error:[]}}
│ EditStatus:{Edit:[]} Errors:{Error:[]}}
╵

2nd Code - Result is Error
resource "iosxe_restconf" "aaa_authentication" {
  path = "Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native/aaa/authentication"
  lists = [
    {
      name = "Cisco-IOS-XE-aaa:authentication"
      key = "login"
      items = [
        {
          "attempts/login" = 4
          "enable/default/group"  = "tacacs+"
          "enable/default/enable" = null
          "login/name"            = "default"
          "login/a1/local"        = null
          "login/a2/group"        = "tacacs+"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Output
iosxe_restconf.aaa_authentication: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Client Error
│ 
│   with iosxe_restconf.aaa_authentication,
│   on main.tf line 187, in resource "iosxe_restconf" "aaa_authentication":
│  187: resource "iosxe_restconf" "aaa_authentication" {
│ 
│ Failed to configure object (PATCH), got error: HTTP Request failed: StatusCode 400, RESTCONF errors {Error:[{ErrorType:application ErrorTag:malformed-message ErrorAppTag: ErrorPath:/Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native/aaa/Cisco-IOS-XE-aaa:authentication ErrorMessage:0: Internal error ErrorInfo:}]} {PatchId: GlobalStatus:{Ok:false Errors:{Error:[]}}
│ EditStatus:{Edit:[]} Errors:{Error:[]}}

